pytelegrambotapi реакции
Нужно узнать реакции в сообщении по айди чата и айди сообщения
Я не нашел такого ответа, но возможно это можно сделать через pyrogram
Заранее спасибо

рекомендую ознакомиться со справкой => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
